# Using Python to scrape data from web xhr feed

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the results of tennis matches from [this webpage](http://www.scoreboard.com/au/tennis/wta-singles/australian-open-2016/results/). In particular I am trying to get the names of the two players, the date/time and the result of the match. I am having two issues:

1. The webpage doesn't display all matches by default - these can only be revealed by clicking "show more matches"at the bottom of the page.
2. When i load the html in beautiful soup, the data doesn't appear to be there. It looks like it is being loaded by some sort of query ('http://d.flashscore.com/x/feed/f_'), but I am not sure how to run this directly.

My code example is below:

```
url="http://www.scoreboard.com/au/tennis/wta-singles/australian-open-2016/results/"

from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
req = Request(url, headers={"X-Fsign": "SW9D1eZo"})
s = urlopen(req,timeout=50).read()
s=urlopen(req, timeout=50).read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(s, "lxml")

match_times=soup.find_all("td", class_="cell_ad time")
players=soup.find_all("span", class_="padl"
results=soup.find_all("td", class_"cell_sa score  bold"
#these all return empty element sets
```

How can i load the page with all results visible? And how can i extract the data described above elegantly?

EDIT:
After the suggestion to use selenium, i have built a function that will load the page using Selenium/Chrome and then send the html to bs4:

```
def open_url(url):
    try:
        from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
        req = Request(url)
        s = urlopen(req,timeout=20).read()
        driver.get(url)
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="tournament-page-results-more"]/tbody/tr/td/a""").click()
            time.sleep(5)
        except:
            print("No more results to show...")
        body=driver.find_element_by_id("fs-results")
        return BeautifulSoup(body.get_attribute("innerHTML"), "lxml")
    except:
        print("Webpage doesn't exist")
```

This means I can reveal all results, but clicking the show more button. Unfortunately the code continues running before the page loads properly, hence when i attempt to grab all the rows containing results:

```
matches=[]
soup=open_url(url)
rrows=soup.find_all("tr")
for rrow in rrows:
    if rrow.attrs['class']!=['event_round']:
        matches.append(rrow)
```

it only get the results that were originally visible. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page use JavaScript to fetch data, if you use `urllib`, you will only get the html code without data.

Use Selenium to scrape the JS page.

Comment: Any chance you can provide an example - I'm not at all familiar with Selenium

Comment: Have adapted code to use selenium (see above). still having issues though - page doesn't finish loading before code continues...

Comment: @user3725021 you should post new question to let community to solve your problem, and accept my answer to close this question.